# Help with log-transformed data in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, lognormal-distribution, ratio, geometric-mean

I am performing a meta-analysis of pharmacokinetic crossover trials with drug-metabolising enzyme activity as their endpoint(s), and as to be expected, the data are a mess and are reported in a frustratingly wide array of formats.

In particular, I want to convert some of the literature-reported, natural log-back-transformed geometric mean ratios of (geometric mean intervention)/(geometric mean control) to the raw scale.

I found [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2978323/) paper which outlines how to do so, and I want to use Method 3 (pg. 6078) "From logarithm to raw", but the formulae require the experimental and control geometric means themselves, and the paper does not mention how to manage the situation in which all you are given is a ratio of geometric means (i.e. no idea what the original values were, just the geometric mean fold-change of experimental over control group response).

For example, one study performed a GLM analysis on the natural log scale, and reports the following information back-transformed to the raw scale:

- LSM +/- SE of the control measurement (raw scale)
- (LSM geometric mean experimental)/(LSM geometric mean control) ratio +/- SE ratio (raw scale)

So with these two pieces of information, is there a way to use in-the-know algebra to calculate the geometric means (raw scale) of both the experimental and control values, so that I can substitute them into the equation on pg. 6079 to estimate the difference in means and its SE on the raw scale?

I.e. information I have:

- LSM +/- SE of the control measurement (raw scale)
- (LSM geometric mean experimental)/(LSM geometric mean control) ratio +/- SE ratio (raw scale)

Information I need from pg. 6078-6079:

- dz = ze - zc, where ze is the mean of the log-transformed experimental values, zc is the mean of the log-transformed control values and dz is their difference
- xgeom, which is either the geometric mean of the geometric means of experimental and control values OR the exponential of the arithmetic mean of the means of log-transformed values

Thanks in advance and kind regards,

Shane Eagles

University of Sydney - Associate Lecturer/PhD Candidate